# values not being accessed inside ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code. The thing is that when I alert the values of id and status inside click functions it works fine but when I try to do so outside that then the value of id is returned undefined initially but alert doesn't work after that. Please help

```
var status = 1;
        var id;
        $("body").on('click','#first' , function() {  
            id = 1;    
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "url",
            data: {id: id, status: status},
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                //alert(data);
                if($.trim(data) == "A") {
                    alert('A');
                } else if($.trim(data) == "B") {
                    alert('B');
                }
            }, error: function() {
                alert("ERROR!");
            }
        });    
        });

        $("body").on('click','#second' , function() {  
            id = 2;
            status = 0;
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "url",
            data: {id: id, status: status},
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                //alert(data);
                if($.trim(data) == "A") {
                    alert('A');
                } else if($.trim(data) == "B") {
                    alert('B');
                }
            }, error: function() {
                alert("ERROR!");
            }
        });
        });
```

Comment: put the ajax inside the click event

Comment: the "id" will not have any value base on your code unless click1 or click2 has been invoked.

Comment: still nothing happening @guradio

Comment: Where specifically is the value undefined?  What value do you expect it to have at that time?  Why?  This code doesn't really make sense to me.  There's no way a user is going to click an element before that AJAX call is made, it's literally on the very next line of code.  What are you actually trying to achieve in this code?

Comment: @pokemon if you put ajax call after initialization it work. can you share what you have changed.

Comment: Updated the question @guradio

Comment: @pokemon can you clarify **still nothing happening** also can you explain what you expect to happened and what is happening right now?

Comment: I expected either A or B to be alerted but nothing is alerted and even if I had an else part inside ajax with alert C then also nothing is alerted.

Comment: @pokemon: Debug.  Are there any errors on the browser's debugging console?  Is the AJAX call made at all?  Does it contain the data you expect?  What is the server's response?  "nothing happening" doesn't tell us anything, literally.

Comment: The AJAX call is not made at all and there is no error in the console.

Comment: What do you mean by server response @David

Comment: @pokemon i think you should include html mark up.. if the ajax is not called maybe you are using class instead of ID

Comment: Actually I had something like `$(this).closest('tr').attr('id')` in id inplace of 1 & 2. And the table rows are being displayed dynamically and the those values of id when alerted inside click function gives correct id's

Comment: when you uncomment `alert(data);` in success what  do you get? can you share html as well?

Comment: @pokemon: By "server response" I mean the response from the server when making the AJAX request.  Though in another comment you claim the AJAX call is not made at all.  When you debug, is the click handler even invoked at all?  What is the HTML being used?  You have to provide more information about where and how this is failing.  We can't debug your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var status = 1;
var id;
$("body").on('click','#first' , function() {  
    id = 1;
    SomethingName();
});
$("body").on('click','#second' , function() {  
    id = 2;
    status = 0;
    SomethingName();
});
function SomethingName(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "url",
        data: {id: id, status: status},
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
    //alert(data);
    if($.trim(data) == "A") {
        alert('A');
    } else if($.trim(data) == "B") {
        alert('B');
    }
        }, error: function() {
    alert("ERROR!");
        }

    });
}
```

Or Try this

```
var status = 1;
var id;
$("body").on('click','#first' , function() {  
    id = 1;
    SomethingName(id,status);
});
$("body").on('click','#second' , function() {  
    id = 2;
    status = 0;
    SomethingName(id,status);
});
function SomethingName(_id,_status){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "url",
        data: {id: _id, status: _status},
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
    //alert(data);
    if($.trim(data) == "A") {
        alert('A');
    } else if($.trim(data) == "B") {
        alert('B');
    }
        }, error: function() {
    alert("ERROR!");
        }

    });
}
```